# water separates into small droplets

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I'm doing a project where a glass is tipped over and the pan pours out of it. I want to make it as similar as possible, but at a certain point the water just starts to separate into small drops and it doesn’t look believable.

I changed the viscosity and speed of the water, but it didn’t help. (I set the viscosity to low, but it didn’t work for me at all)

[image]

In the red squares these are my works where the water was divided. I want to do something like in the photo

I would really appreciate any help that is given

Comment: Did you try playing with the resolution, and the mesh option inside the physics tab ? Both are involved in the results you are getting.